# Can a method in Dart have a semicolon after the closing brace?

Tags: dart

Hi i am new to the Dart programming language, i have been looking at this code for local persistence for a journal app. My confusion came when i came across this:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "journals": List<dynamic>.from(journal.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
```

What confuses me is what does this translate to, i think it translates to the following:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {{
    "journals": List<dynamic>.from(journal.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };}
```

Which is wrong (because Vs Code is shouting @ me), i also thought toJson() is simply a Map variable but again that is wrong,

now if it is a method that means its return type is Map<String, dynamic>, but then where is the return statement in the body of the function?

,my other question is what does it really translate to if we are to remove the short hand, and help me understand what kind of function ends with a semi colon like that, please help a newbie

Comment: `toJson()` is a function that returns a `Map`.  `=> expr;` is shorthand for `{ return expr; }`.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions

Comment: Thank you so much, will definitely check it out

Answer (score 1):

It "translates" (as in: means the same thing as)

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  return {
    "journals": List<dynamic>.from(journal.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}
```

The function returns a single value, which is a `Map` literal.
Map literals have the form `{key: value, ..., key: value}`.

This can be confusing to people coming from modern JavaScript, because JavaScript introduced a function shorthand where `(x) => { ... }` is shorthand for `function(x) { ... }`. The body of a JavaScript `=>` is a statement block. The content of a Dart `=>` is a single expression, the value of which is returned.